# Is there a "stock" chooser for image content providers?

Tags: java, android, file, android-contentprovider

For instance, when I want to attach an image to a text message in the stock Messages app, I get a familiar system dialog presenting the Camera, Gallery, and other image Content Providers.

I want to use this in my own app. I see plenty of libraries that allow the user to choose between Gallery and Camera, but I want *all* of the user's installed Image source to appear.

Is the system dialog from Messages (and other stock apps, such as Mail) really custom for those apps? Do we really need to build our own? Storage Access Framework does not appear to be the right solution since it bypasses the camera (or other image sources that I haven't thought of but may be present on a user's device).

Comment: would you mind showing a picture of what you mean by "stock chooser" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `Intent.ACTION_PICK`

```
  private void selectFileFromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");


    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
        "Select Picture"), requestGallery);
  }
```

It will open a dialog like this that contains all of users app that can be used as an image picker :[image]

And then when user chosses image:

```
   @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == requestGallery) {
        onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
      }
    }

           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
          private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (!uri.toString().contains("file")) {
              if (uri.toString().contains("external")) {//chosen from external storage
                photoUri = Uri.parse("file://" + getRealPathFromURI(uri));
              } else {
                photoUri = Uri.parse("file://" + (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 18
                    ? getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(getActivity(), uri) :
                    getRealPathFromURI_API19(getActivity(), uri)));
              }

            }

          @SuppressLint("NewApi")
          private String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri) {
            return RealPathUtil.INSTANCE.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, uri);
          }

      public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
      }
          @SuppressLint("NewApi")
          private String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            String result = null;

            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

            if (cursor != null) {
              int column_index =
                  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
              cursor.moveToFirst();
              result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            return result;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are asking for can be done using System Access Frame work.
Add Storage Permissions inside the manifest file, and then check if the permission is accepted or not. Then you can open open document choose to let the user choose the image.

**Code**

*Inside some onClick*

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(i, 41);
```

This will open file chooser activity for image files only.

Then you can get back the results inside:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == 41) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                //This is the uri to the file
                //To get the file use the uri
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Still you have to create the BottomSheetDialog on your own, but your job will be drastically reduced as there will be only 2 options : 1. Camera app ,2. File chooser. You will have to handle the camera event on your own and get the image uri.

[image: Android Default File Chooser]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using android image [Android-Image-Cropper by ArthurHub](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

It gives you all the options you are looking for 
[image]